# How to repair (or hide) chipped kitchen cabinets

Tags: doors, kitchens

Our tired old kitchen is getting a make-over!

Is there a method to repair damaged laminate-chipboard cabinet doors? As you can see in the photo the base has chipped away and it is very flaky.

I'm looking for a way to do this without replacing all the doors. Even just painting to hide it all is a possibility but I'm not sure that will work with the flakiness of the chipboard.

[image: chipped kitchen cabinets]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You get new cabinet doors.  You can go the more expensive route and order them from a custom place (made to order are about $50-80 a door for pine depending on size).

You can also go to your nearest salvage store and match their cabinets or doors.  Of course you will have to alter some.

There is just no efficient to repair chipboard.  You would basically have to glue edging onto the cabinets and there would have to be extra material on the inner doors.  It would be ghetto, not look good and not last long.

Answer (score 0):

I say that it's feasible. Not everyone can afford new doors. Scrape away the flaking parts and sand, ensure area is dry. Use wood filler, build up gradually and then once completed and dry, sand to the level of the door. I have similar issues snd intend to use vinyl stick on over the top of mine adter and put new handles on. Going to fill the door with wood filler first so it's solid.

Comment: A) this question is 8 years old. B) The OP was in the middle of a renovation, so one would presume there's some budget for things like this. C) Repairing particle board just generally doesn't go all that well.  Wood filler just doesn't stick to it for long, especially on a high wear surface like a door (where there's obviously been enough wear to cause the chipping in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a product like [Peel Bond](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/xim/primers-sealers/peel-bond), this will stop the flaking, essentially this acts like a glue and locks the substrate down.

Then you can use some wood filler or use bondo if you'd like, reshape the edges as you see fit and then paint accordingly. If you use bondo, keep it tight as it's a lot harder to sand then regular wood filler. I would use Elmer's Wood Filler, it sands easily and I have used it on many mill packs to repair trade damage on corners.