# How would you repair this chipped kitchen cupboard door?

Tags: kitchens, mdf

Looking for some advice on how to fill in the small hole and touch it up so the color matches. I *think* it’s mdf but not 100% sure. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at any of the related questions, like [this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55752/how-to-repair-or-hide-chipped-kitchen-cabinets?rq=1)?

Comment: fill, sand paint. Fill with bondo or wood filler. Sand only the area, paint with touchup paint. Looks like the cabinets are plastic??? So it will be touch to completely hide, but I can't believe it would be worse than what you currently have.

Comment: @LarryBud thanks, how does wood filler compare to bondo?

Comment: IME Bondo is harder, which means more difficult to sand. I you've never used either I'd recommend getting a scape piece of wood, taking a chip out of it, and practice fixing it.

Comment: Great advice, thanks @LarryBud, I will do just that!